# How to avoid curl trying IPv6 name resolution

Tags: dns, curl, ipv6

From a docker container when I try to curl 'another container name', curl first tries to resolve the name to IPv6. This causes few seconds delay because the web server is not reachable over ipv6.

I removed the link local address on the container interface and also disabled ipv6 on the container's lo and eth0 interface. curl still tries to resolve the name to IPv6 first (unless its forced via curl -4).

This seems wrong. Why does curl try to resolve the name to ipv6 even if ipv6 is disabled ?

Comment: How is IPv6 disabled, in particular? Otherwise, `--ipv4` is a relevant flag to `curl` in that situation.

Comment: I removed v6 addresses from /etc/hosts and did the following.. sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0, sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=0, sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1

Comment: @Manohar I can't thank you enough for your answer. Disabling ipv6 was the easiest workaround and saved my tons of hours

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **disabling IPv6 globally does not work**

I still watch a 5s "initialization" delay.
Only the `-4` argument works.
(Same thing with `wget` command)

I've also tried to force iptables rejecting IPV6 traffic.
↪  Nothing changes

#### DNS

My tests show that it's the name resolutions that runs this delay.
If I curl an IP based URL, it's done instantly.

What's strange is that name resolution itself, made with `nslookup` is instant (and contains no IPV6 answer)

Comment: If I put static name resolution in `/etc/hosts` file, it works. But such a bad way...

Comment: I've also tried `curl` alternative such as `httpie` : much better.
Why `curl` & `wget` try to resolv IPV6 specifically

Comment: The developers of `curl` and `wget` saw that IPv6 is being used more often and enabled support in the source code.  If you open a bug in the source code respositories for them, the developers will likely either say `disable IPv6 in the souce code and recompile` or `use the command-line options to disable IPv6`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that behavior by editing `/etc/gai.conf` and uncomment `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100`.

That will however affect more than just `curl`.